# Why won't my binary tree display what's currently in it?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

I'm trying to `display()` my binary tree with what's inside already but for some reason it's not working.
I'm getting nothing as an output.

Maybe my logic for the methods is off? I'm not quite sure.

Here's my `Node.java` file:

*(content missing)*

Here's my `BinaryTree.java` file:

```
public class BinaryTree {
public static Node root;

public BinaryTree() {
    this.root = null;
}

public void insert(Node n, Student s) {
    if(n != null) {
        while(true) {
            if(s.getLastName().compareTo(root.data) < 0) {
                insert(n.left,s);
            } else if(s.getLastName().compareTo(root.data) > 0) {
                insert(n.right,s);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void display(Node root) {
    if(root != null) {
        display(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.left);
        display(root.right);
    }   
}
```

}

Here's my `Student.java` file:

```
    public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String id;

    public Student(String first, String last, String Identification) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        id = Identification;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(String studentId) {
        return id.equals(studentId);    
    }

    public int compareTo(String s) {
        int lengthOfLongestString = 0; // Length of longest string that we will base.
        int i = 0; // Index of current string, will be incremented in for loop below.
        int a = 0; // Index of 
        int b = 0;

        if(lastName.length() < s.length()) { // If the string that's currently inside < incoming string
            lengthOfLongestString = lastName.length(); // Then set the current string as the new length.        
        } else {
            lengthOfLongestString = s.length();  // Else incoming string is the new length.
        }

        if(lastName.charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
            for(i = 0; i < lengthOfLongestString; i++) {
                if(lastName.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i)) {
                    a++;
                    b++;
                    break;
                }
            }       

            if(i == lengthOfLongestString - 1) { // If i = length of last character of the string
                return 0;
            }

            if(lastName.charAt(a) < s.charAt(b)) {
                return -1;
            }   
        }
        return 1;
        }
}
```

Here's my `Main.java` file:

```
public class Main extends Student {

public Main(String first, String last, String ID) {
    super(first, last, ID);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("hi", "purple", "brown");
        Student student2 = new Student("red", "purple", "now");
        Node n = null;

        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.insert(BinaryTree.root, student);
        bt.insert(BinaryTree.root, student2);
        bt.display(BinaryTree.root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor of `Main` is useless and even the `Main extends Student` part.

Comment: @freedev ah yes, you're right.

Comment: Why is the root static? Hint: It shouldn't be

Comment: There is no base condition for your recursive `display()`

Comment: @cricket_007 if my root isn't static, then my `bt.insert(BinaryTree.root, student);` line would throw me an error.

Comment: Your code doesn't display because there is a `while (true)` loop

Comment: As far as I can see, `insert()` never actually inserts anything into anything...

Comment: Just to understand, what is `root.data`, a String?

Comment: @yabva89 That's only because `BinaryTree.root` is a static variable that is useless. You have `Node n`, so why pass the root to the insert method?

Comment: @John3136 Hmm... I don't see how it's not inserting anything.

Comment: @freedev yeah it's a string

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `insert()` method. It is an infinite loop that never stops

Comment: @yabva89 Where does `insert` say `something = s;`? (Which is what it needs to actually store the data).

Comment: Remove the `while(true) ` into the insert function

Comment: @John3136 I thought I was recursively inserting strings onto the tree to either the left or the right

Comment: @yabva89 Yeah, but where does it actually do the insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things wrong here, and it may not solve the problem immediately.

1) `while(true)` is going to spin forever and you never break out of it. Also you have an infinite loop within a recursive statement, which is just poor design.

2) You always are comparing `s` and `root`. You should compare `n.data`

3) You need to assign `n.left` and `n.right` at some point.

4) (Optional) Students can have the same last names.

5) You always insert into a BinaryTree from the root, so passing it in as a parameter seems redundant, but it doesn't need to be static.

```
bt.insert(student);
```

And you could write like this

```
private Node root;

public boolean insert(Student s) {
    return insert(this.root, s);
}

private boolean insert(Node n, Student s) {

    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = n;
        return n == null;  // did you really insert something? 
    }

    if (n == null) return false;

    boolean inserted = false;

    if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) <= 0) { // Compare same names
        if (n.left == null) {
            n.left = new Node(s); // Not sure what this looks like
            return true;       // Inserted a node
        }
        inserted = insert(n.left,s);
    } else if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) > 0) {
        if (n.right == null) {
            n.right = new Node(s); // Not sure what this looks like
            return true;       // Inserted a node
        }
        inserted = insert(n.right,s);
    } else { // Should never get here 
        // Not actually an error
        // System.out.println("Error!!!!!");
    }
    return inserted;
}
```

Comment: I fully understand your code but whenever I do `System.out.println(bt.insert(student));`, `System.out.println(bt.insert(student2));`, I'm getting `false` `false` back to back whenever I change `student2`'s last name.

Comment: If the tree starts empty, that first one should at least be true

Comment: Actually, oops, need to check the root first