# Why won't my binary tree display what's being inserted?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

I want to know why my `display()` method is printing the base case even after inserting items onto my binary tree.  I'm trying to compare last names of students.  All I want is for my tree to display so I can confirm that the `insert()` works.

Here's my `Node.java` file:

```
class Node  {
   Student data;
   Node left;
   Node right;

public Node(Student data) {
    this.data = data;
    left = null;
    right = null;
  }
}
```

Here's my `BinaryTree.java` file:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public Node root;

public void insert(Student s) {
    root.left = new Node(s);
    root.right = new Node(s);
    root = insert(s,root);
}

private Node insert(Student s, Node t) {
    if(t == null) {
        t = new Node(s);
        return t;
    }
    else { 
        if(s.getLastName().compareTo(t.data.getLastName()) < 0) {
            t.left = new Node(s);
            t.left = insert(s,t.left);
            return t.left;
        } else if(s.getLastName().compareTo(t.data.getLastName()) > 0) {
            t.right = new Node(s);
            t.right = insert(s,t.right);         
            return t.right;
        }
    }
    return t;
}

public void display(Node root)  { 
    if(root == null) { 
        System.out.println("Nothing found.");
    } else if(root != null) {
        display(root.right);
        System.out.println(root.data);
        display(root.left);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `Student.java` file:

```
public class Student {

private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String id;

public Student(String first, String last, String Identification) {
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    id = Identification;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean equals(String studentId) {
    return id.equals(studentId);    
  }
}
```

Here's my `Main.java` file:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student("hi", "bye", "testing");
    Student student2 = new Student("out", "some", "names");

    BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
    bt.insert(student);
    bt.insert(student2);
    bt.display(bt.root);
   }
}
```

Here's my `output` in the console:

```
Nothing found.
```

Comment: `if(t == null) { root = t; } ` you are setting the root to `null`

Comment: Your display logic also has a problem, because you are calling `System.exit(0)` when hitting a base case.  This will kill your entire program.  You probably just want to return instead.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari But then I'm inserting to the right and to the left recursively.

Comment: Since the root is always null it is not entering the other cases. `root = insert(s, root)`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I understand where you're coming from.  I tried altering my code to follow your notion but it keeps giving me errors.

Comment: I see problems with both insertion and traversion.  Get insertion working and then worry about displaying.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Where exactly am I going wrong with the insertion?  I felt like it's pretty straight forward.  It's probably my base case that's messing everything up.

Comment: You aren’t ever creating any nodes (with `new Node(…)`). Since your tree is to consist of nodes, you need to do that.

Comment: @OleV.V. I changed up my code, may you please check it out to see if I'm on the right track :)?  I'm still getting the  `Nothing found.` message.

Comment: Id’d say not, sorry. I think your `root` will still always be null, so `root.left = new Node(s);` will throw a `NullPointerException`. If `root` wasn’t null, you’d be replacing both subtrees, thus losing all data except the root.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm so confused, I've been on this for so long.  All this time I felt that I was inserting the right way.

Comment: I think that the contract for `insert(Student s, Node t)` should be: If `t` is null, returns a tree consisting of one node containing `s`. If `t` is not null, returns the tree rooted in `t` with one node added, that node containing `s`. Never returns `null`. If you can code that, you should get insertion right.

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh ok.  I'll try it out & let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @OleV.V. I changed my code up again if you take a look.  My output became `Nothing found.
Student@4b71bbc9
Nothing found.`  I think I'm getting close.

Comment: Spoilers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669114/why-wont-my-binary-tree-display-whats-currently-in-it

Comment: You’re improving! Certainly. I also think that @cricket_007 has been awfully kind and written a helpful answer. Please study that and let’s continue the discussion afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say focus on the insert logic since that's wrong anyway.

You don't need a display method to see the tree. Fire up the debugger, and check the left and right Node object references

1) You're immediately going to hit a nullpointerexception on an empty tree
2) You only need to assign the root on an empty tree, not set every node you can reach to the same student node

For example, it's simply this

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public Node root;

    public void insert(Student s) {
        root = insert(s,root);
    }

    private Node insert(Student s, Node t) {
        if (root == null) return new Node(s);

        if (...) // compare names
```

Then, if you look here, you overwrite anytime you make a `new Node`.

```
    if(s.getLastName().compareTo(t.data.getLastName()) < 0) {
        t.left = new Node(s);  // this is useless 
        t.left = insert(s,t.left);
        return t.left;
```

You need to check when you're at a leaf node, then return accordingly. And you need to return the current Node back up the recursion, not the child.

```
    if(s.getLastName().compareTo(t.data.getLastName()) < 0) {
        if (t left == null) {
            t.left = new Node(s);
       } else {
            t.left = insert(s,t);  // insert using t as the new root 
       } 
       return t;  // return t with its new child
```

Do the same for the right side

If that's not working, try writing out your algorithm for a small 3 node tree, then for a 4-7 node balanced tree

Comment: This is really clear thank you!  I understand the logic 100% which makes total sense but when I tried implementing this, my consoles output is: `Nothing found.
Student@4b71bbc9
Nothing found.
Student@17dfafd1
Nothing found.
`

Comment: Your recursive `display()` method prints `Nothing found` each time it encounters a `null` in your tree. There will typically be a number of those. Instead, print only that message if the *root* is `null`, that is, before (or instead of) calling the recursive method.

Comment: No, @nampa. In the first invocation of `display()` it is, but when you call recursively, `root` is not the absolute root of the tree, just the relative root of the subtree. This may well be null without the whole tree being empty.